# how to add exactly 2nd and 3rd sublists with a list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am exercising for a final exam tomorrow. I am trying a couple of weird examples. For example, I am given a list of sublists like this: `[[1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [8, 9, 10]]`. I want to add the second and third sublists together and return their sum by using a list comprehension. I have tried numerous things, but I am not able to succeed.

I realise that the list comprehension generates a cons pair of each of my sublists and tries to add the second and the third elements of each cons pair. But this is not what I want. I want to output [20], because 2+3+4+5+6 = 20.

I wrote this, where I am trying to only add the second sublist in a cons pair. But then there is no way to also generate the third sublist. So I am kind of stuck.:

```
sumTwoThree::[[Int]]->[Int]
sumTwoThree list = [(x + xs) | (x:xs)<-(list!!1)]
```

I also wrote this:

```
sumTwoThree::[[Int]]->[Int]
sumTwoThree list = [head xs + head (tail xs) | (x:xs)<-list, (length xs > 1)]
```

but this only generates the sublists that have at least 3 elements and then it adds together the 2nd and 3rd elements of those sublists.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use a list comprehension, here?

Comment: Because I am trying to exercise list comprehensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to filter out any sublist that isn't the second or third, then include them in the result.  After that, you use `sum`.  Like so:

```
sumTwoThree xs = sum [x | (i, sub) <- zip [1,2..] xs,
                          i == 2 || i == 3,
                          x <- sub]
```

You cannot accomplish this without using the `sum` function.  This is because a list comprehension is just syntactic sugar for using the list monad.  And you have to fold over a list to compute the sum of its elements.

If you want to really get a good idea about what a list comprehension is, then learn about the list monad, and even try to understand how this works:

```
foo []     = [[]]
foo (x:xs) = [x':xs' | x' <- x, xs' <- foo xs]
```

Then observe what it does:

```
Main*> foo ["123", "abc"]
["1a","1b","1c","2a","2b","2c","3a","3b","3c"]
```